# How to read image from server via emulator

Tags: android

I want to read image from server using android studio via emulator. Please any one help me because I had tried a lot of ways but not yet success.

My peace of code are like this.

In `Acitivity.java` file code is like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);


    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            bitmap = getBitmapFromURL("http://10.0.2.2/img.bmp");
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

And I use this `Function`.

```
public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src){
    try{
        URL url=    new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input=(connection).getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return  myBitmap;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: use Picasso it's the easiest and best way

Comment: Thank you but can you give me peace of code please?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for downloading and caching images.Add this in your dependencies using `compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'` if you are using android studio otherwise add the jar in your libs.

it's a one line code to manage everything :

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

just pass your url and  you are done.

Comment: Ok, let me download and test then i will back.

Comment: @MakameSharif.If this help then can u please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I try many things at last I found this I think this will useful for you. So try this.

Do this in your Activity.

```
new DownloadImageTask(your_imageview).execute("http://10.0.2.2/img.bmp);
```

And method is like this.

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your welcome Bro... if its useful for you then give right to my answer. :)